# Issue with deviantart authentication (PHP)

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I am trying to connect to deviantart via their [oauth2 mechanism](https://www.deviantart.com/developers/authentication). I do get the code to obtain an access token but then I get some strange 404 error when trying to get the access token via file_get_contents. However, when I copy the url I am able to get the access token as desired. Has this sth. do with header settings? This is the code to get the access token:

```
function getAccessToken($code) {
        $url = "https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/token";
        $data = array();
        $data["grant_type"] = "authorization_code";
        $data["client_id"] = $this->client_id;
        $data["client_secret"] = $this->client_secret;
        $data["redirect_uri"] = $this->redirect_uri;
        $data["code"] = $code;
        return $this->sendToDeviantArt($url, $data);
}

private function sendToDeviantArt($url=null, $data=array()) {
        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data),
            ),
        );
        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me hours but apparently, deviantart wants to have a USER_AGENT set. So for the records, this works flawlessly (mind the user_agent variable)

```
    private function sendToDeviantArt($url=null, $data=array()) {
        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data),
                'user_agent' => $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
            ),
        );
        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        return $result;
    }
```

**EDIT:** For the records, we have programmed a wrapper for some deviantart functions and have uploaded [a small library on github.](https://github.com/boxconnect/deviant-php)

Answer (score 0):

This was a pain for me too. Thanks to Jan for the heads up on the user agent. Just thought I'd offer a curl alternative as that's what I was using for this. Obviously edit to your hearts content, but this works if you pass a deviantART api url through it.

```php
function curl($url) {
  // Initiate curl
  $ch = curl_init();
  // Disable SSL verification
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  // Will return the response, if false it print the response
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  // Set the user agent
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
  // Set the url
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  // Execute
  $result=curl_exec($ch);
  // Closing
  curl_close($ch);
  // Will dump a beauty json :3
  return $result;
}
```

```

Example usage to get your access token:

```php
$json = json_decode(curl("https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/token?response_type=code&client_id=0&client_secret=0&grant_type=client_credentials"), true);
$json["access_token"];
```